# Largest element of the set $\{ \sin{1}, \sin{2}, \sin{3}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, alternative-proof

I have to find the largest element of the following set $\{ \sin{1}, \sin{2}, \sin{3}\}$.

I converted every element to the first quadrant so I can use the monotony of cosine, the set becomes: 
$$\Big\{ \cos{\frac{\pi-2}{2}}, \cos{\frac{\pi-4}{2}}, \cos{\frac{\pi-6}{2}}\Big\}$$.

$$\Big|\frac{\pi-6}{2}\Big| > \Big|\frac{\pi-4}{2}\Big|$$

$$\frac{6-\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi-2}{2} > 0  \Rightarrow \frac{6-\pi}{2} > \frac{\pi-2}{2}$$

$$ \frac{4-\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi-2}{2} < 0 \Rightarrow \frac{4-\pi}{2} < \frac{\pi-2}{2}$$

$$ \frac{4-\pi}{2} < \frac{\pi-2}{2} < \frac{6-\pi}{2} \Rightarrow \cos{\frac{\pi-4}{2}} < \cos{\frac{\pi-2}{2}}<  \cos{\frac{\pi-6}{2}}$$ so since cos is monotonically decreesing in the first quadrant, $\cos{\frac{\pi-4}{2}} = \sin 2$ is the biggest element in the set.

Is this correct and is there any easier solution?

Comment: Alternatively, $\sin (\pi-x)=\sin x\Rightarrow \sin(\pi-3)\approx \sin 0.14$ and since $\sin$ is increasing over $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ the result follows.

Comment: Your title has $\sin$ while the body has $\cos$.  Which is correct?  $1$ radian is already in the first quadrant, so doesn't need conversion.

Comment: its sin, but i used the formula $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2} - x} = \sin{x}$ because sin 2 and sin 3 are not in the first quadrant.

Comment: another direct way to compare $\pi-3, \pi-2 ,1$,it is clear $\pi-2>1>\pi-3$,then the result comes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Let's see how rusty my TeX is...)

We could also use trig identities:

$$\sin 2  =  \sin(2·1)  =  2 \sin 1 \cos 1  >  2 \sin 1 \cos \frac{\pi}{3}  =  \sin 1  ,$$

$$\sin 3  =  \sin (2+1)  =  \sin 2 \cos 1  + \cos 2 \sin 1  <  \sin 2 \cos \frac{\pi}{4}  + \cos \frac{\pi}{2} \sin 1  = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \sin 2 < \sin 2 
$$

Thus, sin 2  is the largest of the three values.

Comment: Except that $\cos 1$ is not greater than $\cos \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Just spotted that during your typing apparently:  I think I've strengthed this now... Sorry.

Comment: You LaTeX looks fine...

Comment: @mjqxxxx,you are right, maybe use $\frac{\pi}{3}$ will be good.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner,the 2nd cos1 should be less than $ co s\dfrac{\pi}{4} $.Ok i edit for you.

Comment: actually, restoring it to what I had written originally... (the intention _was_ to bound cos 1 from above using familiar values of cosine)